# Sorting with c++ algorithm

Tags: c++

I want to sort chopsticks by weight and I want the matching pair of chopstick at the end of program. Should I use sort algorithm? I want to sort it by weight means (e.g 110, 90, 110, 90) so in this case I got 2 pair. One having weight 90 and other having weight 110, but how can I track that? I know I have to use counter but how I don not know.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector> 

using namespace std; 

bool myChopsticks (int i, int j) 
{
return (i<j);
} 

int main() 
{ 
int myintergers []= {90, 110, 90, 110}; 

vecotr<int> myvector(myintergers, myintergers+4); 

vector<int>::iterator it; 
sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end()+2);
 cout << "myvector contains:"; 

for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it) 

cout << " " << *it; cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by matching pair of chopstick.

Comment: I am thinking this will be the code

Comment: Is this homework? Post your code so far so we can comment in a meaningful way.

Comment: Much better question than the last - but you should still tag the question with homework as I have done. You will get the best responses by showing what you have thought about and why (and posting as much code as you have)

Comment: As a matter of fact, it looks suspiciously like this homework question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718104/c-program-for-matching-drum-sticks which was also posted by someone with 1 rep (and promptly closed) less than an hour ago.

Comment: I am thinking this will be the code#include<iostream> #include<algorithm>#include<vector> using namespace std; bool myChopsticks (int i, int j) {return (i<j);} int main() { int myintergers []= {90, 110}; vecotr<int> myvector(myintergers, myintergers+2); vector<int>::iterator it; sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+1); cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;}

Comment: This is my first time to ask anything on website so I did not know many things but I will tag this as homework.

Comment: You can post the code inline in the question using "edit" on the question, and the 1010101 "Code" toolbar icon in the edit form.

Comment: @Cool:  The code should go into the question itself, formatted properly.  I just did that for you; feel free to edit further (if you don't like my descriptive text, or want to change the code).

Comment: You want `sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end())` to sort the whole vector; you're just sorting the first element, which does nothing.

Comment: @Cool:  Oh, and your problem description is scanty.  It would help if you could include more detail.  BTW, while we all start out as newbies on a site, not everybody learns from there.  Providing code (even if not in the write format) and tagging as homework are good things to do, so you in particular seem to be learning.

Comment: What do you mean by "the matching pair of chopstick"?  Do you mean two chopstick weights of the same value (e.g. `0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4` would give `2`), or the chopstick numbers (indices) from the original vector (e.g. `7, 5, 6` sorted to `5, 6, 7` would give `1, 2, 0`)?

Comment: @David thanks for that. Now it looks good @Stranger- I want to sort it by weight (e.g 110, 90, 110, 90) so in this case I got 2 pair. One having weight 90 and other having weight 110.

Comment: @Cool: the statement `sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end()+2);` has a problem. You should remove the `+2` because that tries to sort nonexistent elements past the end of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so.

By sorting the chopsticks, you will have them in order. Then, it will be much easier (with just a single iteration through the ordered set) to find the pairs with equal weight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems enough to store a list of chopsticks (possibly in a vector<>) then either iterate through them to find the match(es) and display it.

Alternately a std:mapping implements a binary tree for you that should make the search for matches very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is only one matched pair, then use a `std::map<weight, chopstick>` and insert at given point after doing a `find(newWeight)` call.  If `find()` returns an exact match at any point then you are done.

If there is more than one possible matching pair then use `std::multimap<weight, chopstick>` and then iterate the resulting container to `count()` the number of matches for each distinct value.

If you don't need the actual chopsticks at the end, but just a count of matching pairs, then you can use `std::set<weight>` or `std::multiset<weight>` instead.

Comment: How to use count() in above program?

Comment: I imagine this homework is intended to help you learn independently as well as research.  I don't intend to actually write your code. If you would care to update your question with any alternate attempts, I am sure people will be glad to help you workout why it's not working.  Good luck.

Comment: Here's a pointer to get you started on the multimap container: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ka6hya8(v=VS.71).aspx